# Why doesn't the indefinite integral act as a function even though it is?

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose we have a function that does not involve integrals say $f(x) = x +2$ , $f(3)$ would just be subsituting 3 into the equation. Now suppose

$$
f(x) = \int 2x^2
$$

Supposing we have $f(4)$, what is so special regarding integrals that makes it so that

$$
\int 2(4)^2
$$

and

$$
2*(4)^3/3
$$

do not give the same answer. I have a feeling this has to do with the fundamental theorem of calculus yet I am not sure.

Any explanation would be great!

Comment: The issue here is the order of operations. You first take the anti-derivative, and then you substitute. But what you are doing is substituting first.

Comment: Even if you follow all hints given so far (add the $dx$ term and order of operations) the point is that $\int 2x^2\,dx$ is not a function.

Comment: If you intend to write $f(x) = \int 2\underset{\uparrow}{x}^2\ dx$, then the variable $\underset{\uparrow}x$ is defined twice and ambiguous: as the input of function $f$, or as the variable of integration.

Comment: A better question is, why would you think the indefinite integral is a function even though it isn't?

Answer (score 6):

The entire notation $\int f(x)dx=F$ is just shorthand for saying $F’=f$ - the $x$ on the left and right aren’t exactly the same. Rather $\int f dx$ isn’t really even a function which you can feed values into - there’s that pesky ‘$+C$’ term representing that it’s an entire class of functions which have the desired derivative.  The variable $x$ inside of $\int f(x)dx$ is a dummy variable, analogous to the index variable inside a sum.

Anytime you actually want to substitute variables or do anything with them, you should use definite integrals where substitution actually makes sense. There, when the variable on the left side is substituted for, it fits into the integration bounds, not into the function itself.

For example, let:
$$F(y)=\int^y_0 f(x) dx$$
Substituting $y=3$ is then allowed:
$$F(3)=\int^3_0 f(x)dx$$

Comment: Since OP wrote in the title that the indefinite integral is a function I suggest that we stress the fact that it is not. A function gives a unique value when supplied with an argument but $\int f\,dx$ does not.

Comment: Good point. I updated the answer to highlight that.

Answer (score 1):

In *algebra*, you can combine functions and then set $x$ equal to a value or you can set $x$ equal to a value and then combine the values in the same way, and you get the same result, e.g., $(f+g)(3) = f(3) + g(3)$.  When $h(3) = f(3)$, we have $(h + g)(3) = h(3) + g(3) = f(3) + g(3) = (f+g)(3)$.  So algebraic operations on functions at a point only depend on the function's value at that point.

In *calculus*, operations on functions at a point do *not* depend only on the function values at that point, but on the function values in an interval around that point: two functions with the same value at $x = 3$ need not have the same derivative at $x = 3$. In particular, although the functions $x^2$ and $9$ have the same value at $x = 3$, this does *not* mean $(x^2)'$ and $9'$ are equal at $x = 3$: the graphs of $y = x^2$ and $y = 9$ pass through $(3,9)$ in different ways, so their derivatives at $x = 3$ are different.
Your mistake with indefinite integrals is similar, although it has an additional error because an indefinite integral of a function on an interval is only determined up to an additive constant and thus the indefinite integral has no well-defined value anywhere: it's always ambiguous by $+C$.

The subtlety that operations on functions in calculus don't commute with evaluation at a point is nicely illustrated by the following story.  My father was once a judge at a high school math fair where students gave presentations on various topics (Pythagorean triples, non-Euclidean geometry, and so on). He judged a student whose topic was calculus and he sensed the student did not understand what he was talking about, so after the talk ended they had the following exchange.

"What is the derivative of $y = 3^2$?"

"Six".

"What is the derivative of $y = 9$?"

"Zero."

"Again, what is the derivative of $y = 3^2$?"

"Six."

"Thank you, that's all."

The student did not go on to the next round of the competition.